# Redirects in declarativeNetRequests to Local Resource

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to redirect the request sent to `https://site/script1.js` to a modified script stored locally  `chrome-extension://ext_id/my_script.js`.

(Basically trying to emulate the behaviour of webRequests.onBeforeRequest -> return redirect to local file)

My rules.json :

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "priority": 10,
      "action": 
      { "type": "redirect",
         "redirect" : {"extensionPath" : "/my_script.js"} 
      },
      "condition": 
        {"urlFilter": "https://site/script1.js",
        "resourceTypes": ["script"] 
        }

    }
]
```

If I change the `action type` to `block` the chrome dev tools shows the request as blocked, and the website doesnt load, however on redirects, nothing happens and the request goes through. It doesnt work for Images either.

Is there possibly a workaround for this (to modify the script a site receives from a request)?

---

Edit:
I'll just try to get an image to work first, the declarativeNetRequest Docs single out [Redirects for a script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-Redirect:%7E:text=Redirects%20to%20JavaScript%20urls%20are%20not%20allowed.).

The website (`https://www.example.com/a/b`) sends a request to `https://cdn.example.com/file.jpg`. I want that request to return a file `my_file.jpg' stored locally .
I have :

Rules.json

```
[
{
      "id": 2,
      "priority": 9,
      "action": 
      { "type": "redirect",
         "redirect" : {"extensionPath" : "/my_file.jpg"} 
      },
      "condition": 
        {"urlFilter": "https://cdn.example.com/file.jpg",
        "resourceTypes": ["image"] 
        }

    }
]
```

and Manifest.json includes:

```
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://www.example.com/*"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources":[
      {
        "resources": ["my_file.jpg"],
        "matches" :["https://www.example.com/*"]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Add this path to `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've added some details, it's still not working. I am just trying to make it work with images first .

Comment: Try with `"<all_urls>"` in `matches`. If that works, I'd say this is a bug/deficiency in Chrome. Don't forget to reload the extension btw.

Comment: @wOxxOm no luck with `<all_urls>` ... is there any way to modify javascript before execution ... in a content_script at `document_start` the javascript is fetched from the cdn but not run, so this point seems ideal to change the script, but how can I access it from inside a content_script

Comment: You can redirect to a `data:` URI generated from your image contents "redirect": {"url": "data:image/jpg......"}. You can use an online converter.